# Как удалить лишний спарсенный элемент?

Tags: python, bs4

Всем привет ! Я парсю дату с этого [ресурса](https://www.inform.kz/ru/ozvuchen-gonorar-golovkina-za-titul-nyy-boy-s-derevyanchenko_a3558655).Все бы хорошо,но есть одно но.Когда я получил эти данные (**22 Августа 2019 10:45                         187**) парсится лишние цифры **187**.Как можно убрать эти лишние цифры **187**? Чтобы у меня было при парсинге только так **(22 Августа 2019 10:45)**

Код:

```
def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    item_datetime=soup.find('div',{'class':'date_public_art'}).text
    item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime,date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    print(item_datetime)
```

Вот место где выдергиваю дату с [этой страницы](https://www.inform.kz/ru/ozvuchen-gonorar-golovkina-za-titul-nyy-boy-s-derevyanchenko_a3558655) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того как вы нашли `<div>`:

```
div = soup.find('div',{'class':'date_public_art'})
```

Вы можете перейти к элементу `<i>` и выбрать предыдущий соседний элемент с помощью `.previous_sibling`, это и будет нужный вам текст. `strip()` - для очистки от пробелов по краям строки:

```
print(div.i.previous_sibling.strip())
```

Или вы можете выбрать первый элемент из списка `.contents`, который содержит все элементы, находящиеся внутри `<div>`:

```
print(div.contents[0].strip())
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ и время которое вы мне уделили.Но как это мне поможет срезать лишнею цифру 187 ?

Comment: Так и поможет. Пробовали выполнить код?

Comment: пока не пробовал .сейчас по попробую